# ISNULL alternative?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't often work with T-SQL, but I'm working with someone else's legacy code, and having to make changes to a mountain of SQL written for SQL Server. I encountered this:

```
ISNULL(CAST(DD.High_Margin_Pct AS varchar(10)) + '%', '') AS 'high_margin_percent',
```

as you may notice, this returns '%' even when the value is null.  Is there any concise way to make the percent sign go away when there are no numerals before it?  Or do I just need to use a `CASE` statement and live with the fact that it'll be verbose?

Comment: [That is not what I see](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d811/1).

Comment: run this against SQL Server: `select ISNULL( null + '%', '' )`

Comment: good point by @kyzen below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, with default SQL Server settings, that should *not* always return '%'.  Typically, trying to append a value to a null *should* result in a null, unless you use a function specifically meant to concat nulls in a friendly manner, such as CONCAT or COALESCE.

You can change this behavior with the following command:

```
set concat_null_yields_null on
```

**Be aware** - this is a server-level setting, and will persist beyond your transaction.  You should probably determine if this was configured in this way for a reason, or if maybe someone else set it OFF at some point and never set it back.  It IS recommend to be set ON.

Comment: According to this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx concat_null_yields_null is deprecated in SQL2012.  Even if you are not using SQL2012, you should not use this command because you will eventually want to upgrade to the newer version.

Comment: I should clarify... "concat_null_yields_null off" is deprecated.  Basically, it will always be on.  Developers should not use the OFF option because it will eventually fail (when the DB is upgraded to SQL2012 or newer).

Comment: This does still work in 2012 actually, though like I said, it's recommended to leave ON.  In future versions of SQL Server this may disappear entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I test with

```
select ISNULL(CAST(null AS varchar(10)) + '%', '') AS 'high_margin_percent'
```

The result is fine. No % show even when result is null.